# select function in solaruim dose not response

Tags: php, solr

i have a 3.* version of solarium installed on cent OS the problem is that the function select of solaruim dos not work and there is no result from it although when i run the same version of solarium on ubuntu is work correctly

```
$config = array(
'endpoint' => array(
    'localhost' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 8983,
        'path' => '/solr/',
        'core' => 'collection1'

    )
)
```

);

```
$client3= new Solarium\Client($config);
$query = $client3->createSelect();
$query->setQuery($query_statement);
$query->setFields(array('type_t,book_i,book_name,author,ver_t,publish_t,publishD_t,sub_t,image'));
$query->setRows(100);
```

at here when i var_dum($query)it work and return an object correctly
`enter code here`$resultset2 = $client3->select($query);

but when call a select function there is no response var_dum($result2) is empty
    $num_found=$resultset2->getNumFound();
this is my code

Comment: What is `$query_statement`? What does the solr server log say?

Comment: $query_statement='type_t:"book" AND book_t:"أخبار"';

Comment: error: HTTP request failed' in /home/theleax3/public_html/alwaraq/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php:229

Comment: hi when i do the select out a function it done but the problem arise when i do it in side a function